# Java Script database insertion

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I have a datatable and I add a new row and submit it to an JSP for database insertion. Im getting the following error in JSP. What is the problem with this code.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near '[object HTMLInputElement]' at line 4] with root cause
```

JS - Ajax code to submit to JSP on click of Save button

```
function addRow(table,row)
    {
         var input = $('input', row);
         var params = "id="+input[0].value+"&name="+input[1].value+"&title="+input[2].value+"&code="+input[3].value+"&email="+input[4].value+"&band="+input[5].value+"&location="+input[6].value+"&manager="+input[7].value+"&school="+input[8].value+"&major="+input[9].value+"&years="+input[10].value+"&edu="+input[11].value+"&skills="+input[12].value;
         var settings = {
                  "async": true,
                  "crossDomain": true,
                  "timeout":0,

                  "url": "insertdb.jsp?"+params,
                  "method": "POST",

                  "headers": {
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                    "cache-control": "no-cache"

                  },
                  "processData": false
                }
         $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                var json = JSON.parse(response);
                if(json.responseHeader.status == "0")
                {
                alertify.success("Sucessfully modified the schema field");
                location.reload();
                //alertify.set({ delay : 5000 });

                }
                else
                {
                alertify.error("Error! Please try again");
                }
                  console.log(response);
                });
    }
```

MY JSP

```
<sql:update dataSource="${myDS}" var="result">
        insert into emp_profile1 (EMPID, NAME, JOB_TITLE, JOB_CODE, EMAIL, BAND, LOCATION, MANAGER, SCHOOL, MAJOR, YEARS_EXP, EDUCATION, SKILLS) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?);

    <sql:param value="${param.id}" />
    <c:out value="${param.name}"></c:out>
    <sql:param value="${param.name}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.title}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.code}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.email}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.band}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.location}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.manager}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.school}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.major}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.years}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.edu}" />
    <sql:param value="${param.skills}" />
</sql:update>
response.setContentType("text/html");
<c:if test="${result>=1}">
response.getWriter().print("{'success': true}");

</c:if>
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Then you can accept it and upvote it, by clicking on the check-mark and arrow-up on the left side. If you still have trouble, please provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Error message give us egough info where the problem could be:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL  server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '[object HTMLInputElement]' at line 4] with root cause

The important info is this:

> **'[object HTMLInputElement]'**

Such string should not be in the sql query. Instead of this should be the name-value-pair prepared in as sql.

So the issue would be in the serialization of the html-form.
You make the serialization manually in the line:

```
var params = "id="+input[0].value+"&name="+input[1].value+"&title="+input[2].value+"&code="+input[3].value+"&email="+input[4].value+"&band="+input[5].value+"&location="+input[6].value+"&manager="+input[7].value+"&school="+input[8].value+"&major="+input[9].value+"&years="+input[10].value+"&edu="+input[11].value+"&skills="+input[12].value;
```

I would suggest to examine the the created `params` by calling:

```
console.log(params);
```

Even better would be to use [jQuery serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)